# Modifying the User Agent String in Chromium source code

Tags: browser, user-agent, chromium

Where in the Chromium source code can I modify the browser's User Agent String?

I am working with the Mac OS. Also, I do not want to append to the User Agent. Essentially, I want to change the UA enough so that a website still thinks it is Chrome (as is standard with Chromium UA), while it is not chrome.

I have had issues with appending a unique identifier in that it causes many websites to block my access.

Comment: use user-agent switcher, or whatever plugin that does that for you. no need to change the source code of chromium for that.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to be implemented in the source so anyone using my version over chromium doesn't need to use a user-agent switcher.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely an old question, but it's a question I too have been searching for an answer for. Since StackOverflow results appear in Google search results, and that there isn't another question like this, it's a good idea to document it for others.

**It's currently located in `content\common\user_agent.cc`**

It used to be located in `webkit\glue\user_agent.cc`, but was moved around when Google forked it to make Blink.

Answer (score 2):

Like dangered wolf mentioned, Google Chrome and Chromium build and retrieve user agent from this method `BuildUserAgentFromOSAndProduct` : [Build Chromium's user-agent](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/common/user_agent.cc?type=cs&q=user%20agent&g=0&l=184)

And this is where Chrome will retrieve the final `Chrome/version` string from `GetProductNameAndVersionForUserAgent` : [Retrieve Chrome/version string for user-agent](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/version_info/version_info.cc?type=cs&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=17)